# Red Hat Linux 3 in VMware Workstation 10 hardware question

Tags: linux, vmware

I am running a very old copy of Red Hat 3 from 1999 in VMware Workstation 10 and I cannot get the X11 display server to go above 320*200 resolution. Installing VMware additions is out of the question, so I am wondering what devices should I choose in Xconfigurator to at least get a 1024*768 pixel desktop up. If this is not possible, then I am probably barking up the wrong tree, but I really want to see what the old Gnome 1.0 desktop looked like in action.

Comment: Have you tried `vesa`?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux#Version_history) Red Hat Linux 3 is much older, it's from May, 1996.